# DRY a large chunk of common code with two vastly different uses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dry

I have a 'widget' that comprises an html/css block of code. It is a type of data layout, which I call the **'stack'**.

The stack has bits of `.erb` (Ruby on Rails) embedded in it, which enters the data for each user.

I need to include this stack in multiple places, where it needs to represent **different data from different models**.

So, one stack might contain a field called `@company.name` and the other stack might contain `@project.name || "Unidentified Project"`.

How does one refactor / organize this situation? Options that I can see:

1. Have two separate `stacks`, which would introduce redundancy and inconsistency, but would be an obvious answer to the problem without limit to scenario-specific customization.
2. Include `if` statements for every data point to test which circumstance the stack is being used for, but this is very code-ugly and unsustainably complicated for more than 2 stacks.
3. Some unknown unknown.

How would you tackle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way would be to write the erb in a generic way so that it works for either a project or a company for example, in your Project model you could put:

```
def display_name
  name || "Unidentified Project"
end
```

Then in your Company model put:

```
def display_name
  name
end
```

When you render the ERB, pass in a variable with some generic name like `main_object` and call its `display_name` function.  The ERB code would not know or care what class `main_object` is:

```
<%= main_object.display_name %>
```

If it bothers you to put display-related functions like `display_name` in your models, you could use the Presenter pattern.  A present is basically a plain-old ruby object that you create from your model(s) and then pass to the view.  I saw a good talk on this pattern by Jeff Casimir called "Fat Models Aren't Enough" and the slides are here:
http://en.oreilly.com/rails2011/public/schedule/detail/18514

Answer (score 0):

David's solutions are good. In some situations you may also consider helpers or partials (e.g. if you want to include complex html). For example:

Helper

```
def display_name(object)
  if object.respond_to? :name and object.name
    object.name
  else
    if object.class.respond_to? :human_name
      "Unidentified #{object.class.human_name}"
    else
      "Unidentified #{object.class.name}"
    end
  end
end
```

Partial

```
<%= render :partial => "stack/name/#{object.class.underscore}", :locals => {object.class.underscore => object} %>
```

With any complex ERB in `app/views/stack/name/_project.html.erb`:

```
<label style="<%= "background-color: red;" if project.name.blank? %>">
  <%= project.name || "Unidentified Project" %>
</label>
```